# Crash after adding footer to ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I'm trying to add footer to `ListView` but application crashes after this line of code: `getListView().addView(footerView);`. I'm new to android and this is my first experience with `ListView`.

If is possible I need short explanation of inflate method.

Thanks!

```
  ToDoListAdapter mAdapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
            mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

            // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
            getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

            //TODO - Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file
            TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);

            //TODO - Add footerView to ListView
            getListView().addView(footerView);

            footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    log("Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                    //TODO - Attach Listener to FooterView. Implement onClick().
                    Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(null, AddToDoActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(startNewActivity, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);

                }
            });

            //TODO - Attach the adapter to this ListActivity's ListView
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
```

**Log:**

```
02-19 13:53:39.358: D/dalvikvm(1451): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 6% free 3090K/3276K, paused 19ms, total 31ms
02-19 13:53:39.366: I/dalvikvm-heap(1451): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.196MB for 1127532-byte allocation
02-19 13:53:39.374: D/dalvikvm(1451): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 4189K/4380K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-19 13:53:39.402: D/AndroidRuntime(1451): Shutting down VM
02-19 13:53:39.402: W/dalvikvm(1451): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d4db20)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451): Process: course.labs.todomanager, PID: 1451
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{course.labs.todomanager/course.labs.todomanager.ToDoManagerActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:452)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at course.labs.todomanager.ToDoManagerActivity.onCreate(ToDoManagerActivity.java:56)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-19 13:53:39.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1451):     ... 11 more
```

**Edit:**

Thanks, fixed that problem but now I it seems there is issue somewhere in click listener.

Log:

```
02-19 14:19:02.346: I/Lab-UserInterface(1731): Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()
02-19 14:19:02.346: D/AndroidRuntime(1731): Shutting down VM
02-19 14:19:02.346: W/dalvikvm(1731): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d4db20)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Process: course.labs.todomanager, PID: 1731
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at course.labs.todomanager.ToDoManagerActivity$1.onClick(ToDoManagerActivity.java:65)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-19 14:19:02.350: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(null, AddToDoActivity.class);` why do you have `null`? Use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Eh, thanks. I missed that.

Comment: also post `footer_view.xml`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Change

   ```
   getListView().addView(footerView);
   ```

   To

   ```
   getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
   ```
2. Explanation for inflate function:

   `LayoutInflater().inflate()` just converts a layout xml into an actual View structure.
3. Your second issue:

   Have a look at your click listener:

   ```
   Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(null, AddToDoActivity.class);
   ```

   You cannot start an Intent with null as the context (the first argument)

   Change to this:

   ```
   Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(ToDoManagerActivity.this, AddToDoActivity.class);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

short explanation of inflate method: Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects. see [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)